# Enable year subscription with initial payment in Play Store

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have an app in the Play Store which has both, the initial payment and a year subscription. I want to know if there is any solution to use the initial payment as the first payment in the year subscription.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the purchases returned by  `billingClient.queryPurchases()` you can get the purchase 
time by calling `purchase.getPurchaseTime()` and then you can know the time that has passed since the purchase

```
private static long YEAR_IN_MILLISECOND = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
if (purchase.getPurchaseTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - YEAR_IN_MILLISECOND)
     // the purchase was made more than a year before
```

Comment: I think that this is wrong, I think that the purchase for the app does not appear in the purchase list...

Comment: You are mixing two different things, the payment to install a paid app has nothing to do with in-app purchases

Comment: That is my question. I want to know if there is something to do with that.

Comment: As I said in another thread it is better that you play with a test project, if not you will hardly understand it. Also, I recommend that you do not make your app as a paid one, but add in-app purchases to offer the premium content. People are very reluctant to buy an app without trying it before

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations but my problem is clear. I know the limitations and the drawbacks of paid apps. I just want to know if there is a solution to accomplish the task I am explaining in the description.

Comment: My answer supposed that an in-app-product was purchased at the beginning and then continue with in-app-subscipcion the second and following years. My answer would be a solution if you wanted to charge more for the first year, otherwise it would be better to use subscription from the beginning

Comment: I know but as I said, that is not the situation